# Spacing Evenly Elements of a Form in Bootstrap

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, forms

I have the following todolist web app, and I'm trying to space the two inputs and the button evenly. But I can't figure out by inspecting the elements in the form what element has a margin or padding that pushes the button further down. The form has three elements two inputs and one button. I want the three evenly spaced. If you can let me know how to fix this appreciated.

Link to webapp: http://pctechtips.org/apps/todo/

Code:

```css
body {
  margin: 0 auto;
  height: 100vh;
  color: white;
  /*display: flex;*/
  background: linear-gradient(to bottom right, #6a176a, #7c811b) 100% no-repeat;
}

.navbar-brand {
  color: white;
}

.add-item {
  font-size: 2em;
  margin: 0 auto;
  border-radius: 30px;
}

.list-group {
  color: gray;
  font-size: 18px;
}
```

```html
<title>TodoList App</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/style.css">
</head>

<body>
  <!-- navbar -->
  <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-drak bg-dark mb-4">
    <a class="navbar-brand" href="#"><i class="fa fa-thumb-tack" aria-hidden="true"></i> Todo<strong>List</strong></a>
  </nav>
  <!-- /navbar -->
  <!-- todoList -->
  <div class="container">
    <div class=" add-item text-white text-center border col-sm-12 col-md-10 col-lg-8 mb-4">
      <a class="new-todo text-white text-center" href=""><i class="fa fa-plus-circle" aria-hidden="true"></i> Enter new todo item</a>
      <div class="add-item text-center col-sm-12 col-md-12 col-lg-8">
        <form class="mb-4">
          <div class="form-group">
            <input type="text" class="form-control" id="formGroupExampleInput" placeholder="Todo Title">
          </div>
          <div class="form-group">
            <input type="text" class="form-control" id="formGroupExampleInput2" placeholder="Todo Description">
          </div>
          <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg col-12">Submit Todo</button>
        </form>
      </div>
      <!-- horizontal line -->
      <hr>
      <!-- list items -->
      <h1 class="heading-4">Todo List Items</h1>
      <ul class="list-group mt-4 pb-4">
        <li class="list-group-item d-flex justify-content-between align-items-center">
          Cras justo odio
          <span class="badge badge-primary badge-pill">14</span>
        </li>
        <li class="list-group-item d-flex justify-content-between align-items-center">
          Dapibus ac facilisis in
          <span class="badge badge-primary badge-pill">2</span>
        </li>
        <li class="list-group-item d-flex justify-content-between align-items-center">
          Morbi leo risus
          <span class="badge badge-primary badge-pill">1</span>
        </li>
        <li class="list-group-item d-flex justify-content-between align-items-center">
          Morbi leo risus
          <span class="badge badge-primary badge-pill">1</span>
        </li>
        <li class="list-group-item d-flex justify-content-between align-items-center">
          Morbi leo risus
          <span class="badge badge-primary badge-pill">1</span>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
```

Answer (score 1):

In your class `.add-item` you are applying a `font-size` in EM units which I believe is the problem.  The way font sizes are calculated when EM is specified can cause inconsistent 'stacking' issues where font sizes compound up or down far more than expected.

Removing this declaration, or changing it from `2em` to `2rem` resolves the issue.

```css
body {
  margin: 0 auto;
  height: 100vh;
  color: white;
  /*display: flex;*/
  background: linear-gradient(to bottom right, #6a176a, #7c811b) 100% no-repeat;
}

.navbar-brand {
  color: white;
}

.add-item {
    font-size: 2rem;
margin: 0 auto;
  border-radius: 30px;
}

.list-group {
  color: gray;
  font-size: 18px;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Gn5384xqQ1aoWXA+058RXPxPg6fy4IWvTNh0E263XmFcJlSAwiGgFAW/dAiS6JXm" crossorigin="anonymous">

<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-KJ3o2DKtIkvYIK3UENzmM7KCkRr/rE9/Qpg6aAZGJwFDMVNA/GpGFF93hXpG5KkN" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.12.9/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-ApNbgh9B+Y1QKtv3Rn7W3mgPxhU9K/ScQsAP7hUibX39j7fakFPskvXusvfa0b4Q" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JZR6Spejh4U02d8jOt6vLEHfe/JQGiRRSQQxSfFWpi1MquVdAyjUar5+76PVCmYl" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>


<div class="container">
  <div class=" add-item text-white text-center border col-sm-12 col-md-10 col-lg-8 mb-4">
    <a class="new-todo text-white text-center" href=""><i class="fa fa-plus-circle" aria-hidden="true"></i> Enter new todo item</a>
    <div class="add-item text-center col-sm-12 col-md-12 col-lg-8">
      <form class="mb-4">
        <div class="form-group">
            <input type="text" class="form-control" id="formGroupExampleInput" placeholder="Todo Title">
          </div>
          <div class="form-group">
            <input type="text" class="form-control" id="formGroupExampleInput2" placeholder="Todo Description">
          </div>
          <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg col-12">Submit Todo</button>
        </form>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
```

Comment: I was about to post the same answer but Robert was faster! :-)

Answer (score 0):

That's because `form.mb-4` has a computed `line-height:96px`. Resetting it to `1.5rem` fixes the issue :

```css
body {
  margin: 0 auto;
  height: 100vh;
  color: white;
  /*display: flex;*/
  background: linear-gradient(to bottom right, #6a176a, #7c811b) 100% no-repeat;
}

.navbar-brand {
  color: white;
}

.add-item {
  font-size: 2em;
  margin: 0 auto;
  border-radius: 30px;
}

.list-group {
  color: gray;
  font-size: 18px;
}
form.mb-4 {
   line-height: 1.5rem;
}
```

```html
<title>TodoList App</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/style.css">
</head>

<body>
  <!-- navbar -->
  <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-drak bg-dark mb-4">
    <a class="navbar-brand" href="#"><i class="fa fa-thumb-tack" aria-hidden="true"></i> Todo<strong>List</strong></a>
  </nav>
  <!-- /navbar -->
  <!-- todoList -->
  <div class="container">
    <div class=" add-item text-white text-center border col-sm-12 col-md-10 col-lg-8 mb-4">
      <a class="new-todo text-white text-center" href=""><i class="fa fa-plus-circle" aria-hidden="true"></i> Enter new todo item</a>
      <div class="add-item text-center col-sm-12 col-md-12 col-lg-8">
        <form class="mb-4">
          <div class="form-group">
            <input type="text" class="form-control" id="formGroupExampleInput" placeholder="Todo Title">
          </div>
          <div class="form-group">
            <input type="text" class="form-control" id="formGroupExampleInput2" placeholder="Todo Description">
          </div>
          <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg col-12">Submit Todo</button>
        </form>
      </div>
      <!-- horizontal line -->
      <hr>
      <!-- list items -->
      <h1 class="heading-4">Todo List Items</h1>
      <ul class="list-group mt-4 pb-4">
        <li class="list-group-item d-flex justify-content-between align-items-center">
          Cras justo odio
          <span class="badge badge-primary badge-pill">14</span>
        </li>
        <li class="list-group-item d-flex justify-content-between align-items-center">
          Dapibus ac facilisis in
          <span class="badge badge-primary badge-pill">2</span>
        </li>
        <li class="list-group-item d-flex justify-content-between align-items-center">
          Morbi leo risus
          <span class="badge badge-primary badge-pill">1</span>
        </li>
        <li class="list-group-item d-flex justify-content-between align-items-center">
          Morbi leo risus
          <span class="badge badge-primary badge-pill">1</span>
        </li>
        <li class="list-group-item d-flex justify-content-between align-items-center">
          Morbi leo risus
          <span class="badge badge-primary badge-pill">1</span>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems that the .add-item class manipulates the button.

You can try

css:

```
.test {
    font-size: 1rem;
}
.test button {
    font-size: 1em;
}
```

Html (wrap content with a ):

```
<div class="test">
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg col-12">Submit Todo</button>
</div>
```